# NameError in PortfoliosController#index uninitialized constant Portfolio::PortfolioUploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

This is my file portfolio.rb
I am having a problem with this code, if grayed out:
 mount_uploader :thumb_image, PortfolioUploader
 mount_uploader :main_image, PortfolioUploader
these two lines then I have acces to my Portfolio page with my placeholders and my portfolio seed, with all the information.
When unmark those two lines of code I have the title of this post as an error. I tried everything to solve it. with no success.

```
  class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :technologies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :technologies,
                                reject_if: lambda { |attrs| attrs['name'].blank? }

  include Placeholder
  validates_presence_of :title, :body, :main_image, :thumb_image

  mount_uploader :thumb_image, PortfolioUploader
  mount_uploader :main_image, PortfolioUploader

  def self.angular
    where(subtitle: 'Angular')
  end

  def self.by_position
    order("position ASC")
  end

  scope :ruby_on_rails_portfolio_items, -> { where(subtitle: 'Ruby on Rails') }

  after_initialize :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.main_image ||= Placeholder.image_generator(height: '600', width: '400')
    self.thumb_image ||= Placeholder.image_generator(height: '350', width: '200')
  end
end
```

This other part of my code is my file _portfolio_item.erb

```
 <div class="card" data-id="<%= portfolio_item.id %>">
    <%= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image unless portfolio_item.thumb_image.nil? %>
  <p class="card-text">
    <span><%= link_to portfolio_item.title, portfolio_show_path(portfolio_item) %></span> <%= portfolio_item.subtitle %>
  </p>
</div>
```

My portfolio_uploader.rb is:

```
class PortfolioUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base


  storage :file

  def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

My _portfolio_item_html.erb

```
<div class="card" data-id="<%= portfolio_item.id %>">
    <%= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image unless portfolio_item.thumb_image.nil? %>
  <p class="card-text">
    <span><%= link_to portfolio_item.title, portfolio_show_path(portfolio_item) %></span> <%= portfolio_item.subtitle %>
  </p>
</div>
```

Any other information that I need to provide for any help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if `carrierwave gem` is properly installed? Check with the command:

```
bundle show carrierwave
```

If it is installed but still not working you might have to add `/app/uploaders` to the autoload_path in order for the uploader to be 'seen'.

Check this [issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/399).

Comment: Nope. No luck. I checked the carrierwave and it is installed, then I checked the link and I still no luck. My tree has /app/uploaders. Thanks anyway.